# jupyter print in loops is printing trash

Tags: python, jupyter

hi when i use the print in this way:

```
 for name in names:       
        progress.value +=1
        print(progress.value, "de ", len(names), end="\r")
```

i get a kind of bug like this

[image]

i was looking in google and here but i had no succeed, i was hoping you people can help me why is this happening and how to stop it. thanks in advance
 i dont know how exactly end="\r" works but i use it because i dont want to spam all the prints, i just want to see the current one

Comment: `\r` is actually carriage return. A carriage return returns the cursor to the beginning of the same line. Are you sure you still need this?

Comment: i use it because i dont want to spam all the prints, i just want to see the current

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `"\r"` as the line separator?

Comment: well i dont know how exactly it works but i use it because i dont want to spam all the prints, i just want to see the current

Comment: You should explain in your original post what you're trying to do.